# VBA script select specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little script that gets data form a website.

```
    Sub importmatches()

Dim QT As QueryTable
Dim URL As String
    
URL = "https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=6"

Set QT = Sheet1.QueryTables.Add( _
                Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
                Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A2"))
                 
With QT
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.AdjustColumnWidth = False
.WebFormatting = xlNone
.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
.WebTables = "7"
.Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

But let's say I only want column 1,4 and 7. Tried everything that I could find but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Read everything and then select the columns you want. Don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: @StureS Thank you. I'm rather new at this. So how do I do this?

Comment: you have the whole table you can now reference specific columns from that table with formulas

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but as I said I'm new to this. Any tips or pointers how to do this?

Comment: This is not a place where you get your programming problems solved by the push of a button. This is the place where people are finding ideas from others how to solve their own programming problems. 
Huge difference!

Ask yourself: Do I want to learn or do I want to copycat?

Comment: you can use = A1 in cell E1 for example to reference column A row 1 etc you can use index match to target columns by headers etc.... the problem with querytables and additionally deleting from querytables is that they are expensive operations - but if only the one table and you don't need optimized performance it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you started.

Read the comments

```
Public Sub importMatches()

    Dim QT As QueryTable
    Dim URL As String
        
    URL = "https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=6"
    
    Set QT = Sheet1.QueryTables.Add( _
                    Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
                    Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B2"))
                     
    With QT
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .WebFormatting = xlNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = "7"
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    ' Set a reference to the result range
    Dim qtResultRange As Range
    Set qtResultRange = QT.ResultRange
    
    ' Define the column numbers to delete
    Dim colsToDelete As Variant
    colsToDelete = Array(1, 4, 7)
    
    ' Delete from end to beginning
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = UBound(colsToDelete) To 0 Step -1
        qtResultRange.Columns(colsToDelete(counter)).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next counter

End Sub
```

PS. I suggest that you use [Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-what-is-power-query) instead of the legacy MS Query

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm agree that Power Query is the much better option and I'm using it. But the file also needs to work on a Mac and I can't refresh the connections on a Mac